# Invalid command name while executing ("after" script)

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.x

As solve this problem? I'm running this code, window is created, but in console appears message on the error. I think problem the fact that is "after" loop not terminate but the window already destroyed.

Code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import time

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.label = tk.Label(text="")
        self.label.pack()
        self.update_clock()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def update_clock(self):
        now = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        self.label.configure(text=now)
        self.root.after(1000, self.update_clock)

app=App()
```

A message in console:

```
invalid command name "66120320callit"
while executing
"66120320callit"
("after" script)
```

Sorry for my small information in first post. I'm using Spyder IDE, and bugs see in spyder console, wherein run repeatedly my code. A description this bugs I find in the python bug tracker as "wait_variable hangs at exit"

Comment: That's strange. It works on my machine. (once I correct the indentation on the lines following `def __init__`)

Comment: works for me as well!

Answer (score 14):

If you destroy the window, whatever "after" jobs that have already been scheduled may run. If the window is destroyed and this job interacts with a widget that has been deleted, you'll get this error.

You can either put a `try` around the code and ignore such an error, check that the window exists before trying to configure it, or put a handler in for when the main window is destroyed to delete any pending "after" jobs.

Comment: If you have a manual quit button, you can use the `after_cancel()` method to cancel an `after` method before calling `root.destroy()` to kill your program. Documentation here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm

Comment: The link above is dead. Found it on the wayback machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20201112030233/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm

Answer (score 9):

TL;DR: Use `tkinter.Tk.quit()`

**Background**

I was getting these 'errors' as well. They're not actual exceptions, they're just annoying to see being spammed in the terminal when running unittests.

I had tried a lot of things, including overriding the `after` method in `tkinter.Tk` to keep track of any queued methods and then calling `tkinter.Tk.after_cancel()` automatically before calling `tkinter.Tk.destroy()` as @GabrielStaples commented.

So I was getting these errors even though there were no queued `after` methods at the point of `destroy()` being called.

**My solution**

What worked for me was calling `tkinter.Tk.quit()` to destroy the window instead of `destroy()`. I read that `quit()` doesn't stop the `mainloop` but it seems fine. Any methods queued by `after` aren't called after `quit()` has been called.

Perhaps somebody could explain any consequences I'm not aware of if there are any

Comment: `.quit()` doesn't destroy the window. It only stops the `.mainloop()` that is currently running.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because my module was named "setup" and I also had a setup.py file. When calling setup.py somecommand, you will get "invalid command name 'somecommand'".

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and solved by just using the plain Python's `exit()` instead of Tkinter's `root.destroy()` or `tkinter.Tk.quit()`.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was creating an exit button that ran a function when clicked, the function would just have the below 2 lines in it:

```
self.withdraw()
self.quit()
```

This allowed the GUI to be closed successfully and would then continue running the rest of the code (if any) in the script.

---

Editing your code above to the following fixed it for me:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.label = tk.Label(text="")
        self.label.pack()
        
        self.buttonCloseWindow = tk.Button(self, text='Close Window', command=self.close_window)
        self.buttonCloseWindow.pack()
        
        self.update_clock()
        self.mainloop()

    def close_window(self):
        self.withdraw()
        self.quit()

    def update_clock(self):
        now = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        self.label.configure(text=now)
        self.after(1000, self.update_clock)

app=App()
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to this issue is to define a `protocol` for when the window is deleted (closed) `WM_DELETE_WINDOW`. In my example, I'm prompting the user with a Yes/No messagebox to make sure the closing was not accidental. But if you are just testing, you can remove that, and the close button will `withdraw()` and `quit()` the application.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox
import time

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.label = tk.Label(text="")
        self.label.pack()
        self.update_clock()

    def update_clock(self):
        now = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        self.label.configure(text=now)
        self.after(1000, self.update_clock)

def on_closing():
    response=tkinter.messagebox.askyesno('Exit','Are you sure you want to exit?')
    if response:
        app.withdraw()
        app.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
    app.mainloop()
```